# Passing Long array to a JSNI function

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

How do I pass a `Long[]` array or `List<Long>` to a JSNI function like this:

```
public native void updateData(Long[] data)/*-{
    waveform.update({
        data: [0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0]
    });
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, for various reasons.

- a Java array (whichever its type) would be an opaque object to JSNI. You have to use a `JsArray` (or `JsArrayNumber` or etc.). Same for a `java.util.List`.
- `java.lang.Long` would be an opaque object to JSNI
- even with `long` it wouldn't work, because you cannot pass a `long` to JSNI. This is because not all longs can be represented as JS numbers. The equivalent of a JS `Number` is `double`.

You have to copy your `Long[]` into a `JsArrayNumber`, and cope for the possible overflows when down-casting the `long` value into a `double` value.